# How to loop through class children of a struct?

Tags: swift2

```
struct List {
    class Item1: Holdable, Throwable {
        var property1 = "A"
        var property2 = "B"
    }

    class Item2: Holdable {
        var property2 = "A"
        var property3 = "B"
    }

    class Item3: Throwable, Catchable {
        var property4 = "A"
        var property5 = "B"
    }
}
```

I have a list like this. I am able to call the items one by one through

```
List.Item1()
```

But if I want all of the Holdable items, how can I get them?

Comment: I've tried Mirror, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @demirb think about your struct as about a namespace, where you declare some classes. your struct has no properties at all. List.Item1 gives you just compiler error. let i1Type = List.Item1.self gives you a List.Item1.Type, let i1 = List.Item1() gives you an instance of that type. that is all ...

Comment: I added a "()" at the end of "List.Item1". Just missed it. But thats not the case. I already am able to access the items one by one. But I want to loop through 100s of items. And the only solution I can come up with is putting all those classes in different types of arrays and calling those arrays which is a lot of extra work.
If there was only a way to turn this into an accessible object, that would be great.

Comment: @demibr by my best knowledge, there is no other runtime way to do it, sorry ... Without creating your struct, it exists only in your source file. Even though you create it, it has no properties and your class declarations exits only in your source file too.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a separate variable and adding every single class. Now I can use map/filter easily. Though, when I need to add a new class obj, I have to add it to 2 different locations :/

Answer (score 0):

look at this 'self explanatory' example

```
struct S {
    class A{}
    class B{}
    struct C{}
}

let a = S.A.self    // S.A.Type
let b = S.B()       // instance of S.B class
let c = S.C()       // instance of S.C struct
let s = S()         // instance of struct S without any property
```

this should not compile at all

```
let a = S.A // error!!
let b = S.B // error!!
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @trojanfoe please, see my notes below the OP's question.